# XOR command fails

Tags: bash, xor

I am trying to create an One Time Pad for cryptography, But I am stuck in an error

The plan is

- Generate Text
- Generate Key
- Convert text and key from Ascii to binary
- Create Cipher using Key_binary XOR text_binary

```
#!/bin/bash

#Create Message #1
plaintext=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 0-9 | head -c8`
sleep 1

#Generate Random Sequence
key=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 0-9 | head -c8`

#Ascii to Binary Convertion
key_bin=$(echo $key | perl -lpe '$_=unpack"B*"')

plaintext_bin=$(echo $plaintext | perl -lpe '$_=unpack"B*"')

plaintext_bin_size=${#plaintext_bin}

key_bin_size=${#key_bin}


    for ((i=0; i < $plaintext_bin_size; i++)); do
        byte=$((${plaintext_bin[$i]} ^ ${key_bin[$i % $key_bin_size]}))

        cipher="$cipher($byte)"
    done

    echo -e "$cipher"
```

But I get
    `syntax error: operand expected (error token is "^ ")`

Comment: Why don't you just do it all in Perl, rather than starting 1x bash, 2x cat, 2x tr, 2x head, 2x Perl?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: `plaintext_bin` and `key_bin` are plain variables, not arrays, so accessing them like `${plaintext_bin[$i]}` will not work. Also, the way you're generating the key is going to be wildly nonuniform. Finally, I recommend running it through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and cleaning up what it points out.

Comment: Unless being an expert in the field and related math, custom cryptography is a slippery slope. And custom cryptography implemented in shell, is warranted disaster and blame for using one of the least appropriate languages to for this kind of task.

Comment: This is for an assignment and to help me learn bash. @LéaGris can you elaborate on why bash is not appropriate?

Comment: @texonec238 Shell script is not a general purpose language. It lacks a lot of the features that cryptography relies on, like high precision floating-point, good entropy sources (`$RANDOM` or `/dev/URANDOM` are weak entropy). And more importantly, shell lacks hardened process insulation and its interpreters can be switched to anything.  Shell can be used to call proper cryptography tools like the GnuTLS, gpg, or ssh. It cannot be used to process cryptography on its own, not even reliably enter PIN codes.

Comment: high precision floating-point → high precision math, reliably enter PIN codes → securely and confidentially enter PIN codes

Comment: Extending @LéaGris comments: shell scripts generally pass data as parameters, and parameters are effectively public information (e.g. `ps` can show what parameters were passed to all running programs). For example, if `echo` weren't a bash builtin, `echo $plaintext` would make the plain text fully visible with `ps` (albeit only for a short time). You could use `<<<"$plaintext"` instead, but depending on the OS that may write the plaintext to disk, leave it there for an unclear amount of time, then delete it without overwriting (so it's actually still on the disk).

Comment: Also, bash doesn't really have data types, making type confusion easy; for example, it looks like you expect `$key` to be treated as a (decimal) number, but it's being treated as a series of character codes, so every "byte" of `$key_bin` will be between 00110000 and 00111001. Actually, even if it were treated as a decimal number it still wouldn't be uniformly random, since 999999999 = (hexidecimal) 3b9ac9ffn, the first byte of the key will almost always be below (hex) 3c (so its first two bits will almost always be 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing solely on the syntax error ...

As mentioned in comments, `${variable[...]}` is an array reference but your variables are not arrays. Net result is you're trying to access array entries that do not exist, ie, you're trying to run an `xor / ^` operation against blank fields.  We can generate the same error with:

```
$ echo $((   ^   ))
-bash: ^ : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "^ ")
```

Assuming the intention is to access the individual digits/positions of the values stored in a variable try `${variable:start:length}`, eg:

```
$ x=123456

$ echo "${x:0:1}"      # start at 0th position for length of 1
1

$ echo "${x:2:2}"      # start at 2nd position for length of 2
34
```

Pulling this into the current code:

```
byte=$(( ${plaintext_bin:i:1} ^ ${key_bin:((i % key_bin_size)):1} ))

### the embedded ((..)) are redundant so this also works:

byte=$(( ${plaintext_bin:i:1} ^ ${key_bin:i % key_bin_size:1} ))
```

Comment: Yeap! That solved it and it made me understand the process. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Bash is choking on:

```bash
byte=$((${plaintext_bin[$i]} ^ ${key_bin[$i % $key_bin_size]}))
```

... which it interprets as:

```bash
byte=$(( ^ ))
```

The reason is that `plaintext_bin` and `key_bin` are no arrays but mere strings. To extract the Nth character from a string variable, use the `${var:N:1}` notation instead:

```bash
byte=$(( ${plaintext_bin:i:1} ^ ${key_bin:i % key_bin_size:1} ))
```